# $E(X_n | X_m) = X_m \mu^{n-m}$ for $ m\leq n$ for branching process $X_n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, markov-process

Let $X_n$ be the size of the $n$th generation in an ordinary branching process with $X_0 = 1, E (X_1) = \mu$, and Var$(X_1) > 0$. It is claimed that for $m \leq n$

$$E(X_n | X_m) = X_m \mu^{n-m}$$  and
$$E(X_nX_m | X_m) = X_m^2 \mu^{n-m}$$

I know that $E(X_n) = \mu^n$, but I don't understand the reasoning behind or the way of computing these conditional expectations. Any hint?

Comment: The latter follows from the former using the tower rule. What’s the problem with the former, you just start branching from which point? And how many branching steps you do from there?